# AWS Application Load balancer path routing issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I have a fairly comprehensive application load balancer set up that routes based on host name.

However, I'm trying to introduce the following but can't get the path routing to work.

i.e.  I have them in this order.

1. licence.example.com/api -> Target Group B
2. licence.example.com -> Target Group A

What I'm seeing is everything is routed to Target Group A.

I have Rule 1 set to host licence.example.com, path: /api/*
And Rule 2 set to host licence.example.com

I've tried changing the order by swapping them around.  And I've tried adding a path to rule 2 as /* but it doesn't work.

Is the AWS load balancer not capable of this most basic configuration?
Am I going to have to throw it out and use nginx?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Two problems.**

1. The order displayed in the UI is important. Rules higher up are list are a higher priority. So first I had to ensure the match with the path occurred first.
2. The requests to /api/* come through to the application with the path /api/ included.  No rewrite like nginx which would strip it off. So the fix was to make a small change to the app listening at Target Group B to expect the /api/ path.  I made this a config value and then it all worked.

Comment: Hi @Matt can you please have a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58640453/path-routing-application-load-balancer-for-react-application  Any input would be highly appreciated