# Path Routing: Application Load Balancer for React Application

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, routes

I'm trying to create path routing in AWS application load balancer.

Example:

1. `apple.mango.com/vault` goes to `instance1` port 80 and nginx routes it to `/var/html/reactApp1/build/`
2. `apple.mango.com/flow` goes to `instance2` port 80 and nginx routes it to `/var/html/reactApp2/build/`

My configuration look something like this:
[image]

Also, for both `/var/html/reactApp1/build/` and `/var/html/reactApp2/build/`, I have them hosted normally say `mango.com` and `apple.com` and they work just fine.

**Problem Statement:**
When the application is visited via path routing like  `apple.mango.com/vault` or `apple.mango.com/flow` it reaches the correct machines/root but fails to load the sites as expected.

Upon inspecting the blank page, it does not load the node-modules:
[image]

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What do the nginx access and error logs show?

Comment: @Matt Nginx access logs shows proper access logs everytime I hit the request.

Comment: Do you mean it shows a valid get and result returned?

Answer (score 1):

I know this question was asked since almost 2 years, but I think I found the solution, so even if it is not usefull now, it can be important in the near future:

In the rules of your load balancer you must enable one rule to allow redirect the traffic to your app when it try to search /static/... because that is the bundle.js created by react:

[image]

I hope this will be as useful for you as it has been for me.